# UIKit Toggle element to be hidden by default

Tags: html, css, toggle

I am using the UIKit bundle CSS with an ASP.NET site. I am using toggle to show/hide comments attached to a section of HTML.

```
                    <div class="uk-card-footer">
                            <div id="toggle-animation" class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-margin-small">
                                <p>Commetns here about various things that I wanted to mention to you </p>
                                <hr />
                                <p>Some more comments from someone else right here!</p>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#toggle-animation" class="uk-icon-button" uk-icon="comment" uk-toggle="target: #toggle-animation; animation: uk-animation-fade" uk-tooltip="Comments"></a>
                            <a href="" class="uk-icon-button" uk-icon="heart" uk-tooltip="Like"></a>
                            <a href="" class="uk-icon-button" uk-icon="forward" uk-tooltip="Detail"></a>
                    </div>
```

However, the content (the two

sections) starts off or defaults as visible. How do I adjust this so that the user has to click the button to toggle the information to visible initially? Rather than to invisible initially as appears to be the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Answer is near that. If you are using the uk-hidden class it blocks everything. as written here: https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/3026 just add the attribute hidden to your div.

```
<div class"" hidden><p>Something</p></div>
<button uk-toggle="your settings">See more<button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation isn't very specific about this, but what you need is to toggle a [custom class](https://getuikit.com/docs/toggle#custom-class).

In the `uk-toggle` attribute, you want to add `cls: uk-hidden;`. Then, on the element that you want to show when your button is clicked, you want to add the class `uk-hidden`.

```
<div id="toggle-animation" class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-margin-small uk-hidden">
    ...
</div>
<a href="#toggle-animation" class="uk-icon-button" uk-icon="comment" uk-toggle="target: #toggle-animation; animation: uk-animation-fade; cls: uk-hidden" uk-tooltip="Comments"></a>
```